# Django path and routing

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

My folder structure inside the app:

```
pwa->static->pwa->serviceworker.js
```

and

```
pwa->templates->indexPWA.html
```

**How can I refer to the `indexPWA.html` inside the `serviceworker.js`?**

`var filesToCache = ["indexPWA.html"]` doesn't work, cause it's not the right path, but what is the right one?

Comment: What do you want to do in your JS file?

Comment: it's a serviceworker, so it should write the indexPWA.html to the cache. Another solution would be if i get the indexPWA.hmtl from the views.py but i've no idea how a can get a template at static/pwa/indexPWA.hmtl from the render function

Comment: "../templates/indexPWA.html"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the path in which you address the *indexPWA.html* page in the browser.

Example:

```
       var filesToCache = ["/indexPWA.html"]

       var filesToCache = ["/"]
```

You can check the correct path by opening *indexPWA.html* in the browser and check for the words which are after **127.0.0.1:8000/** in the url bar.